# Dynamically draw lines between multiple GeoPoints in Android MapView

Tags: android, line, android-mapview

I am developing an application that has a few custom overlays on a MapView - representing vessels. When selecting a vessel, I am showing its previous positions on the map, again with custom overlay items, and I would like to connect them with a line.

Some relevant problems I saw here were solved by overriding the Draw method, and by hard-coding the GeoPoints' coordinates in the Draw method. That does not help me at all, since I have many points from different vessels, and cannot hard-code them all into Draw.

Is there a simple way to just draw a line between the GeoPoints inside the for loop used to display the custom overlays??

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: Why do you think you need to hard code the geopoints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Projection` from the `MapView` in order to convert GeoPoints to "screen" points. After that you can use `Path` to draw the line that you want. The first point should be specified with `path.moveTo(x, y)` and the rest with `path.lineTo(x, y)`. At the end you call `canvas.drawPath(path)` and you are done.

Below is a code from my draw() method that draws a polygon around a set of points. Note that you do not have to use `path.close()` as I did on my code.

```
public void draw(android.graphics.Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow){
    if(shadow){
        if(isDrawing == false){
            return;
        }
        Projection proj = mapView.getProjection();

        boolean first = true;
        /*Clear the old path at first*/
        path.rewind();
        /* The first tap */
        Paint circlePaint = new Paint();
        Point tempPoint = new Point();
        for(GeoPoint point: polygon){
            proj.toPixels(point, tempPoint);
            if(first){
                path.moveTo(tempPoint.x, tempPoint.y);
                first = false;
                circlePaint.setARGB(100, 255, 117, 0);
                circlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
                canvas.drawCircle(tempPoint.x, tempPoint.y, FIRST_CIRCLE_RADIOUS, circlePaint);
            }
            else{
                path.lineTo(tempPoint.x, tempPoint.y);
                circlePaint.setARGB(100, 235, 0, 235);
                circlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
                canvas.drawCircle(tempPoint.x, tempPoint.y, CIRCLE_RADIOUS, circlePaint);
            }
        }
        /* If indeed is a polygon just close the perimeter */
        if(polygon.size() > 2){
            path.close();
        }
        canvas.drawPath(path, polygonPaint);
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
    }
}
```